# How do I make Sublime Text 2/3 not open previous tabs when I launch it?

Tags: sublime-text

[image]
Everytime  i open Sublime , these tabs automatically opens. How do i fix this. I am unable to find any setting for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Sublime Text 2**

Check the content of the directory `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Settings` for a file called `Session.sublime_session`

If those files are included in there, remove them

**Sublime Text 3**

ST3 stores the session files under:

```
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session
```

Comment: Unfortunately ST2 seems to create that file again. I solved that creating an empty file with read only permissions. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the files been renamed `Auto Save Session.sublime_session`, so to rm its `rm -f ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Auto\ Save\ Session.sublime_session`

Comment: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/` does not exist?

Comment: How can This be done on windows?

Comment: This solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29236116/755405

Comment: On Windows, it's "%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Local\Session.sublime_session"

Comment: Thank you. I opened huge file with my Sublime Text and it crashed Sublime everytime open any sublime instance.
Removing the sublime_session help me to use the sublime text again

Answer (score 49):

There is actually a better solution implemented in Sublime Text. Select `Preferences-> Settings - User` and set `remember_open_files` and `hot_exit` to false. The resulting file should look like this:

```
{
    "remember_open_files": false,
    "hot_exit": false
}
```

(All the possible settings can be seen in `Settings - Default`.)

Just restart Sublime Text afterwards (it may be required to restart the program two times, one time to apply the settings) and it should start up without any open files.

Note: I only was able to test this with Sublime Text 3, but I am pretty sure that this settings exist in version 2 as well.

Comment: this is the right answer ( it also work on sublime 3 )

Comment: Although this is correct, this does not help if Sublime Text crashes on start-up.

Comment: What is the difference between the two: remember open files and hot exit? Because if I have hot_exit set to true, then the condition "remember_open_files" seems to be automatically satisfied (i.e. true hot_exit will also keep the open tabs :)

Answer (score 1):

In **Sublime Text 3**, below worked for me.

> $ rm ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Auto\ Save\
>   Session.sublime_session