# Sublime opens 2 windows

Tags: sublime-text

When I open sublime, it shows 2 windows like so:

[image]

What can I do to remove the 2 windows and force sublime to open only one window. Also I don't want sublime to remember any previous tabs

I already tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554388/why-does-sublime-from-terminal-open-two-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

This can be achieved also choosing the option from menu:

```
View >> Layout >> Single
```

This will set Sublime Text to display a single column layout.

Comment: Now it is a single window, But it is remembering the tabs that I opened before

Comment: @rjmessibarca In theory, closing all files and then closing Sublime editor should clear open files from Sublime cache. So next time you'll open the editor you should find no open tabs.

Comment: I wanted  to be able to just click on the cross on top left and then when I reopen sublime, the previously opened tabs should not be there

Comment: @rjmessibarca Try these answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/180142/how-do-i-make-sublime-text-2-3-not-open-previous-tabs-when-i-launch-it